# How can I hide specific Windows update?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

Two months ago Microsoft has released update (part of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997732/managementeventwatcher-for-win32-processstarttrace-no-longer-working-in-win-8-1)) which is causing problems to my software. I've found solution how to uninstall it, but after uninstallation, Windows installed it again.

I know the update mustn't be hidden without user permission - this is not a part of my question.

I'm looking for a way how to hide this update. I accept just any solution, but I prefer `Batch` or `VB-script`.

Comment: Windows Update has a [COM API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): you can program against that. You exp3ected to have tried to start development *before* asking specific questions on [SO] should you get stuck. If you don't know how or where to start then search for a tutorial ([SO] does not recommend tutorials: such information ages too fast).

Comment: Go into Windows Update, right-click the update you want to hide, and click Hide.

Comment: @SomethingDark I know that I can do it manually, but I'm looking for some automatic way - using a script.

Comment: That's a security update.  You shouldn't hide it even *with* user permission.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [What is the "Get Windows 10" Tray Item and How Do You Remove It?](http://www.howtogeek.com/218856/how-do-you-disable-the-get-windows-10-icon-shown-in-the-notification-tray/) and follow it [mutatis mutandis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutatis_mutandis):

- To uninstall an update (e.g. `KB3035583`):

  - Manually: first open Windows Update and click “Installed Updates” in the bottom-left corner. To quickly find `KB3035583`, you can sort by name. Once you’ve located it, right-click and choose “`Uninstall`”. Restart the computer then.
  - Or programmatically  `wusa /uninstall /KB:3035583` using [Windows Update Standalone Installer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/934307)
- If you have Windows updates set to download and install automatically, this means that if you uninstall this update, it will be reinstalled automatically a few days later. To hide the `KB3035583` update and prevent it from being reinstalled, right-click on it in the Windows Update application and select “`Hide update`”.

  - To hide an update programmatically, see [Opmet's answer](https://superuser.com/a/922921/376602) to another question at SuperUser: [How to disable the “Get Windows 10” icon shown in the notification area (tray)?](https://superuser.com/q/922068/376602)

Comment: Thanks, [Opmet's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/922068/how-to-disable-the-get-windows-10-icon-shown-in-the-notification-area-tray/922921#922921) is exactly what I want.