# Why Win32_ProcessStopTrace-Events arrive, but Win32_ProcessStartTrace doesn't?

Tags: c#, wmi

Consider following code:

```
using (ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher("select * from Win32_ProcessStopTrace")) {
    watcher.EventArrived += (object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) => {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} stopped", (string)e.NewEvent["ProcessName"]);
    };

    watcher.Start();

    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);

    watcher.Stop();
}
```

When I run this code (as admin), it notifies me as soon as I close any other application.

First: When using `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` instead of `Win32_ProcessStopTrace`, I don't get any notification for starting processes. Why is that?

Second: If there's a possibility to monitor (every) starting processes, can I suspend them, do other stuff and then continue their execution?

---

**Version info:**

- Windows 8.1 x64 (v6.3 Build 9600)
- .NET Framework v4.0.30319 (in
  directory), 4.6.00081 (according to VS)
- (I don't know whether
  specific updates are needed, so you could ask for them)

Comment: Your Windows version matters, this query was broken for a while.  I know it died in Win8.1, perhaps other versions.  It is back alive in Windows 10.

Comment: @HansPassant I have Win 8.1. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Not sure why you are telling me this, I already mentioned that it is broken in 8.1

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I read "version matters", added version information and then I read "broken in Win 8.1", so I asked for alternatives

Comment: I already mentioned that too, it is no longer broken in 10.  If you don't want to update for some mysterious reason then call Microsoft Support instead of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HansPassant pointed out, this query doesn't work for Windows 8.1. This is related to a [security update (KB3045999)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3045999). Under [Known issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3045999#mt2) there's a link to a [hotfix (KB3094199)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3094199) to fix this problem. After installing this hotfix and rebooting my computer, the query finally worked.